# How to check if Docker is installed in a Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, docker

I need to check in a shell script if Docker is installed (Ubuntu server).

I came up with this, but the syntax is not correct.

```
if [[ which docker && docker --version ]]; then
  echo "Update docker"
  # command
else
  echo "Install docker"
  # command
fi
```

I also tried `if [ which docker ] && [ docker --version ]; then`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using suggestions from the answer in rickdenhaan's comment:

```
if [ -x "$(command -v docker)" ]; then
    echo "Update docker"
    # command
else
    echo "Install docker"
    # command
fi
```

Comment: What does `-x` do? For me `if command -v docker; then` is working.

Comment: It tests if a file exists and is executable. The `command` command returns the docker command's location, then the `-x` flag tests that it there and able to execute.

Comment: The brackets are an alias the the `test` command. Run `man test` to see all the flags and their descriptions.

Comment: Is there any reason why `command -v docker` would be preferred over `which docker` ?

Answer (score 8):

This one is working for me:

```
if [[ $(which docker) && $(docker --version) ]]; then
    echo "Update docker"
    # command
  else
    echo "Install docker"
    # command
fi
```